# Query is returning Null

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, amazon-aurora

I am trying to run a query on the query editor in my AppSync console. This AppSync API connects to my Aurora Serverless. I have no idea why my mutation is returning null.

This is my schema:

```
input CreateMyAWSServiceInput {
    id: Int!
    shortName: String
    longName: String
    description: String
    serviceRegionName: String!
    feedUrl: String
    imageUrl: String
}

type Mutation {
    deleteMyAWSService(id: Int!): MyAWSService
    createMyAWSService(createMyAWSServiceInput: CreateMyAWSServiceInput!): MyAWSService
    updateMyAWSService(updateMyAWSServiceInput: UpdateMyAWSServiceInput!): MyAWSService
}

type MyAWSService {
    id: Int!
    shortName: String
    longName: String
    description: String
    serviceRegionName: String!
    feedUrl: String
    imageUrl: String
}

type Query {
    getMyAWSService(id: Int!): MyAWSService
    listMyAWSServices: [MyAWSService]
}

type Subscription {
    onCreateMyAWSService: MyAWSService
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createMyAWSService"])
}

input UpdateMyAWSServiceInput {
    id: Int!
    shortName: String
    longName: String
    description: String
    serviceRegionName: String
    feedUrl: String
    imageUrl: String
}
```

This is my query:

```
mutation create {
  createMyAWSService(createMyAWSServiceInput: {
    id:3,
    shortName:"abc",
    longName:"defghi",
    serviceRegionName: "123"
  }){
    id
    shortName
    longName
  }
}
```

These are my results:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createMyAWSService": null
  }
}
```

Is there a reason why I'm receiving null and not able to write to my table?

Answer (score 2):

This issue was due to my data source role not having a policy to write data into the RDS. How it was resolved was by going to the IAM and finding the role of the datasource, and then adding in a RDS full permission policy to it.